# R function for a list

Tags: r

If you can help with my function below that would be great.

```
fix_dt_coupon <- function(tbl,dt)
{
    tbl$dt <- ymd_hms(tbl$dt)
}
```

Error message when trying to use it:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dt", value = numeric(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 22873 In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

dput(head(dt)) output

structure(c("function (x, df, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", "    if (missing(ncp)) ", 
"        .External(C_dt, x, df, log)", "    else .External(C_dnt, x, df, ncp, log)", 
"}"), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - it's a function from lubridate.  **y**ear-**m**onth-**d**ay-**h**our-**m**inute-**s**econd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to subset by just pasting in a string - try:

```
fix_dt_coupon <- function(tbl, dt)
{
    tbl[[dt]] <- ymd_hms(tbl[[dt]])
}
```

I'm assuming your tbl is a data.frame and dt is a column name. Use dput(dt) to help people answer your question.

Comment: 'tbl' is a data.frame and 'dt' is a string I'm trying to convert to a date variable,'data.frame': 22873 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ REG_DATE     : Factor w/ 22842 levels "2010-07-21 13:44:02",..: 20897 8200 10652 19295 9049 9683 14250 2664 18237 18113 ...

Comment: can you put dput(head(dt)) in the question using edit?

Comment: you most likely to need to use as.character() on your REG_DATE column too.

Comment: sorry, I meant dput(head(DATA)), where data is the data you trying to use in the function